# There exists a function which satisfies assumptions $1.$ and $2.$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, derivatives

As an exercise, I need to find a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}^*\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $\eta>0$ exists such that
$$ 1.\quad |f^{\prime}(x)|\le \eta\quad \mbox{ as } x\to +\infty;$$
$$ 2.\quad f^{\prime}(x)\ge \frac{1}{x^2}\quad \mbox{ as } x\to 0$$.

I am thinking that condition $2.$ implies that $f^{\prime}(x)\ge 0$ as $x\to 0$, thus $f$ is increasing for $x\to 0$ and, by condition $1.$ it is increasing between $0$ and $\eta$, decreasing between $-\eta$ and $0$ as $x\to +\infty$.

However, I am not able to exhibit an example for a this kind of function.

Could someone please help me?

Moreover, it is also required to say that $f^{\prime}(x) =\frac{\cos x}{\sin^3 x}$ satisfies $1.$ and $2.$.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is there some reason you can't choose $f'(x) = \frac1{x^2}$ when $0<x<1$ and $f'(x)=0$ for $x>1$ (that is, say, $f(x) = -\frac1x$ when $0<x\le 1$ and $f(x) = -1$ when $x\ge1$)? If not, what further requirements does your example need to satisfy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all if $f^\prime(x)\ge\frac{1}{x^2}$ then by fundamental calculus theorem:

$f(x_0)-f(\epsilon)=\int_\epsilon^{x_0}f^\prime(x)dx \ge\int_\epsilon^{x_0}\frac{1}{x^2}dx=\frac{1}{\epsilon}-\frac{1}{x_0}$

for some $x_0$ small enough and for all $0<\epsilon<x_0$ by condition 2.

thus $f(\epsilon)\le f(x_0)+\frac{1}{x_0}-\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ and $\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)=-\infty$

the most natural example seems to be $f(x)=-\frac{1}{x}$ which is checking condition 2 and condition 1 for every $\eta$ that you have chosen beforehand

Second part of your question : the function you quoted clearly doesn't check the first condition because : $\lim_{x\to n\pi}|f^\prime(x)|=\infty$ for any integer $n$

Comment: Olivier, thank you for the answer. Does $f(x) =-\frac{1}{x}$ also satisfies $f^{\prime}(a) =a$ (i.e. $f^{\prime}$ has a fixed point) and $f^{\prime\prime}(a)<1$? I checked that it holds true  with $a=1$, but if you would confirm it could be great for me. Sorry if I ask, but I just realize that I posted an answer with some assumptions missing.

Comment: Yes for $a=1$ you've got :$f^\prime(1)=1$ and $f''(1)=-2<1$ ;  $a=1$ is the only fixed point of $f'$